# How to execute git pull command automatically from server using post-receive script

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-flow

I have a working tree stored in the bitbucket server and it has a git-flow enabled. I have 2 branches which are `develop` (staging) and `master` (production). Staging and production are stored in a different server. I would like to automate the `git pull` command on server when I pushed files to the `develop` branch. I've created post-receive file in `/var/www/test-dev/.git/hooks`.

`GIT_WORK_TREE` is clone repo from bitbucket

`GIT_DIR` cloned files from bitbucket

I've tried to commit from my local and push it to the bitbucket, pull the updated files from local, but the post-script seems to be not working. I've also made the post-receive script executable by running the command `chmod u+x post-receive`.

Here's a sample post-receive:-

```
GIT_WORK_TREE="git@bitbucket.org:username/test.git"
GIT_DIR="/var/www/test-dev"
DEPLOY_ALLOWED_BRANCH="develop"

echo "***** GIT_DIR: $GIT_DIR"
echo "***** GIT_WORK_TREE: $GIT_WORK_TREE"

while read oldrev newrev refname
do

    BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
    NEWREV="$newrev"

    if [ "$DEPLOY_ALLOWED_BRANCH" == "$BRANCH" ]; then
        git checkout -f "${BRANCH}" || exit 1
        git reset --hard "$NEWREV" || exit 1
    fi

    echo "githook: Will deploy '${BRANCH}' branch to the project '${GIT_DIR}'"
done

exit 0
```

I've tried to manually execute `post-receive`, but I'm getting empty string for branch. I expect the output would be the develop branch.

Here's the message I'm getting when executing post-receive

```
***** GIT_DIR: /var/www/test-dev
***** GIT_WORK_TREE: git@bitbucket.org:username/test.git

githook: Will deploy '' branch to the project '/var/www/test-dev'
```

Is there something I missed or my setup is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see many problems in the hook. You set `GIT_WORK_TREE` to a remote URL; it must be a path to a local directory. `GIT_DIR` must point to `.git` directory or a directory one level up.

You set `GIT_WORK_TREE` and `GIT_DIR` at the very beginning of the script so every `git` commnd runs with these settings, even those that need access to the original repository. Let me try to rewrite the script this way:

```
DEPLOY_ALLOWED_BRANCH="develop"

while read oldrev newrev refname
do

    BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
    NEWREV="$newrev"

    if [ "$DEPLOY_ALLOWED_BRANCH" == "$BRANCH" ]; then
        GIT_WORK_TREE="/var/www/test-dev"
        GIT_DIR="/var/www/test-dev/.git"

        echo "***** GIT_DIR: $GIT_DIR"
        echo "***** GIT_WORK_TREE: $GIT_WORK_TREE"

        echo "githook: Will deploy branch '${BRANCH}' to the project '${GIT_DIR}'"

        git checkout -f "${BRANCH}" || exit 1
        git reset --hard "$NEWREV" || exit 1

        exit 0
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @phd! I've got it working, but I'm having an error on the master branch like it has to be a working tree. It's successfully uploading just unsure what the error means or how to debug it. I've also missed to setup git bare repo into the server, then added there post-receive script instead. Though, I'll try the sample code you've provided above. Thanks again!